# Outlook VSTO - How to check if MailItem exist (new email dialog is open and is active inspector)

Tags: c#, vsto, mailitem

I have code like this

```
var mi = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as MailItem;

if (mi != null)
{
    mi.Attachments.Add(myFilePath);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it assumes that new mail dialog will be opened (the `ActiveInspector` `CurrentItem` is a `MailItem`).  However, that is not always so in my case.

If that is not the case, then above code getting `mi` will throw `NullReferenceException`.

How do I check if I have new mail dialog opened and if so then use above line to get it; otherwise create new MailItem (new mail dialog)?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var mi;

if (MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem != null)
{
    // get existing
    mi = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as MailItem;
}
else 
{
    // otherwise, create new one
    mi = MyAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
}

// now use it to attach file   
if (mi != null)
{
    mi.Attachments.Add(myFilePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out what is returned from the ActiveInspector method call first.

```
var mi;
var inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
if (inspector != null)
{
   // get existing
   mi = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
}
else 
{
   // otherwise, create new one
   mi = MyAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
 }

// now use it to attach file   
if (mi != null)
{
   mi.Attachments.Add(myFilePath);
}
```

See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Much appreciated Eugene!